# URL redirect with SSL and site name change

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, ssl

I have a URL www.site-name.com that has been moved to www.sitename.com and then an SSL certificate has been installed on the new site (sitename.com). I have an .htaccess file for both sites.

For the old site I have redirects for site-name.com to sitename.com as follows:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site-name.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.site-name.com$
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.sitename.com/$1 [R=301,L]

</IfModule>
```

This works except that if you type in https: //www.site-name.com you get a security message and no redirect. Most .htaccess knowledgebases tell you how to redirect from http to https or from site-name.com to sitename.com but I need to know how to redirect for both at once. I need http: //www.site-name.com to redirect completely to https: //wwwsitename.com. Can someone help me get the site redirected without the security message? I don't understand why the old url resolves with the https protocol.

UPDATE:
As requested the security warning I get is "Your connection is not private". The error code associated is NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

Here is some additional information that might be important in solving the problem: 
When searching for the site in Google both sitename.com and site-name.com come up in the search. When you click site-name.com it tries to go to https: //site-name.com instead of redirecting to the correct site: https: //sitename.com

Comment: If you don't have an SSL certificate for www.site-name.com then why would you think that it would even be a relevant domain address to incorporate for your redirect.  If you're trying to redirect both sites to https then just use the htaccess code you have on your first site and this code on your new site's htaccess file.RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. www.site-name.com is the originating domain and I want it to redirect to the new domain www.sitename.com. The original domain doesn't have an SSL but it still resolves when you use https in the URL. That isn't the desired effect. I don't want it to resolve - I just want it to redirect. It is an issue because when you search for the site in Google it tries to (for some reason) take you to https://www.site-name.com. So instead of getting to the new site it gives a security warning.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on`:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sitename.com[nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.sitename.com/$1 [r=301,nc]
```

Comment: This one didn't work for me. It just showed me the directory contents of www.site-name.com

Comment: Looks like it's the SSL certificate problem for `https: //www.site-name.com` that others suggessted.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your redirect block to this:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site-name\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.site-name\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.sitename.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

If that doesn't work, your SSL certificate might not be valid for both `sitename.com` and `www.sitename.com`. If that is the case, simply dropping the `www.` from the redirect should prevent the warning. However, if you want requests to `sitename.com` to also redirect to `www.sitename.com` (or vice versa), you will need to have a valid certificate for both.

**EDIT:**

Based on remarks in the comments below, you also need valid certificates for `site-name.com` and `www.site-name.com` if you want them to be accessible over HTTPS and get redirected.

Comment: Those rewrites work similar to how my original ones do. Everything resolves except when there is https added to the original url. So if I type in www.site-name.com it redirects to www.sitename.com. But if I type in https://www.site-name.com it gives a security warning. How can I get that piece to redirect to the right URL?

Comment: What is the warning you get? Please add it to your original question.

Comment: That should be "But if I type in https: //site-name.com it gives a security warning."

Comment: That probably means you don't have a valid certificate for `site-name.com`.

Comment: Do I need one if I just want internet traffic to redirect to the new site? I have one for sitename.com

Comment: Yes you do. By design, browsers will not allow you to access sites over HTTPS if they do not present a valid certificate exactly matching the domain and subdomain. Even if you're just redirecting, you still need to allow browsers to make it to the redirection part of the request. In your case, it's falling short and throwing that warning.

Comment: I understand the domain and subdomain requirements but this is two different domains. Hosted on the same shared server but different URL's. The issue isn't between 'www' and no 'www' but when the original URL has https added in place of http. It should get a timed out request but instead gives the "connection not private" error message but you can still click through to the old URL. www.site-name.com should not be accessible no matter what protocol is used.

Comment: If I understand your problem correctly, you're trying to redirect `https://site-name.com` to `https://sitename.com`. In order to do this, you need a valid SSL certificate for `site-name.com`, even though you're redirecting right away.

Comment: No. I'm trying to redirect http: //site-name.com to https: //sitename.com. The https: //site-name.com is a confusing side effect. It has never been a secure site at that URL. When searching for the site in Google both sitename.com and site-name.com come up in the search. When you click site-name.com it tries to go to https: //site-name.com instead of redirecting to the correct site: https: //sitename.com

Comment: It sounds like you have logic somewhere that's redirecting to HTTPS before ever reaching the above .htaccess. It might be other redirect rules somewhere, or maybe something in server configuration. Hard to tell from what you've posted, unfortunately.